# Why does ServiceReference implement Comparable?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, osgi

[ServiceReference](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/ServiceReference.html).[compareTo](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/ServiceReference.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29) is defined in terms of service.ranking and service.id.  However, it seems that service.ranking could be updated dynamically/asynchronously via [ServiceRegistration](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/ServiceRegistration.html).[setProperties](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/ServiceRegistration.html#setProperties%28java.util.Dictionary%29).  This means compareTo between two ServiceReference can vary from call to call, which makes ServiceReference unusable for all the typical uses of Comparable.  For example, Arrays.sort will misbehave if the ranking is updated asynchronously while sorting, and TreeSet<ServiceReference> will be corrupted if the service.ranking is updated at all.

1. Why does ServiceReference implement Comparable?  It would seem better to not have compareTo at all, or at least not implement Comparable to avoid encouraging developers to use APIs inappropriately.
2. Are there any data structure suggestions for maintaining a sorted list of services?  In particular, for use by DS bind methods for cardinality="0..n" references.

Comment: You could sort a list, assume that none will be updated during the (hopefully short) time that the sort is in progress, and display the "current" ranking.  Repeat every few seconds and you have a "live display".

Comment: I could do that, or decorate-sort-undecorate.  The time complexity of doing that isn't great, and it still leads me back to #1.

Answer (score 2):

ServiceReference objects are not immutable. There is no requirement that Comparable objects are immutable, so I am not sure why you expect ServiceReference object to be so.

The ServiceTracker uses the Comparable nature of ServiceReferences to maintain the sort order for tracked services.

In DS 1.2, we introduce a new "updated" method for references which is called when the service properties of a referenced service change. You can use this method to trigger a resort of your data structure when a referenced service's service properties change.

Comment: I don't expect ServiceReference or Comparable to be immutable.  I understand that compareTo could be useful.  I don't understand when using a ServiceReference as a Comparable is ever useful, but I do have examples of when it's harmful.  Do you have examples for when it's useful?

Comment: As I mentioned above, it is used by ServiceTracker to maintain a sorted set of tracked services. So it is quite useful in some cases. It just does not work for your case where you have a set of services that does not resort when a service in the set is changed.

Comment: I do not see a method on ServiceTracker that returns a list of sorted services.  Am I missing it?  In any case, ServiceTracker doesn't actually use the Comparable interface as such, it just uses the compareTo method, so I still don't understand why it's useful for ServiceReference to implement Comparable.

Comment: Isn't the compareTo method the method from the Comparable interface? In version 1.5 of the tracker package (will be in Compendium 4.3), there is a new method to return a SortedMap from ServiceTracker.

I am not sure there is much else to add to this discussion. ServiceReference implements Comparable and has well defined behavior which is consistent with the Comparable contract. I am sorry that your use case does not work well with ServiceReference's Comparable behavior.

Comment: Will the compendium 4.3 SortedMap be kept up-to-date, or will it be a snapshot (ala getServices)?  If up-to-date, how will it do that (question #2 above)?  If snapshot, how will it avoid mutations will sorting (e.g., decorate-sort-undecorate)?  What is the use-case would be negatively affected if ServiceReference still had a .compareTo method but didn't implement Comparable (question #1 above)?

Comment: The SortedMap is a snapshot like everything else in ServiceTracker. The tracker itself is the entity which handles the mutations in the set of tracked services. ServiceReference implements Comparable. It is not going to change to not implement Comparable. That would be a breaking API change. If you do not care for the way Comparable is defined for ServiceReference then you are free to not use it.

Comment: Ah, then the ServiceTracker SortedMap isn't what I was looking for (a "live" data structure).  I'm still curious how it's implemented without racing with concurrent service.ranking updates.  Can you share?  I know the implements Comparable can't be removed now and I know I'm free not to use it, but it would be nice if the javadoc said something "ServiceReference is consistent with the Comparable contract, but because service.ranking can be updated concurrently, it should not be used with APIs that require immutable Comparable, such as Arrays.sort or TreeSet."

Comment: As I said, the SortedMap is a snapshot created at the time it is requested. The ServiceTracker is the object which tracks changes in services. A returned SortedMap does not change after you request it.

Comment: I understand.  However, even if the ServiceTracker is only creating a snapshot TreeMap (for example), it still needs to protect against service.ranking mutations while it's building the snapshot.  e.g., A:0, B:2, mutate A to 4, C:3 will result in [C, A, B].  Regardless of the position of A in the result, I think it's wrong for C to be before B.  If ServiceTracker is directly using ServiceReference as Comparable, it is susceptible to the issue.

Comment: ServiceTracker internally synchronizes when creating the snapshot, so the snapshot is correct at the time of creation. There is always a race here. Even if the returned SortedMap faithfully resorted as tracked services changed, any iteration of the map's entries would detonate upon such a change (e.g. ConcurrentModificationException) making the map useless to any user. This is why ServiceTracker always returns snapshot answers: they can be safely iterated over.

Comment: ServiceTracker synchronizes add/remove/update calls on itself, but not against service.ranking, which is used by compareTo.  The tracker needs to protect itself, and the only solution I have is to wrap ServiceReference, snapshot ranking, insert into TreeMap, and unwrap on the way out.  Even with that, Map.get is unusable if service.ranking changes.  Perhaps it's easiest to just doc that the SortedMap is unreliable if service.ranking changes asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

It's Comparable so that when it is registered, it's in the correct order.

If you change the properties *after* registering, it will have no effect on moving the object around in the order.

This isn't the only JDK class to have this behaviour. Right or wrong, a `Delayed` object is ordered in a `DelayQueue` when it's *added*. If you change the delay *after* adding it to the queue, it will be available via `.take()` in the order as if it had not been changed.

Comment: Adding an element to a DelayQueue requires O(lg n) compareTo on the element to add it to the priority heap.  What if the service.ranking mutates while adding it into the DelayQueue?